# Error establishing a database connection (Set-up locally)

Tags: php, database, mysql, phpmyadmin, configuration

This is my first time working on Wordpress and accessing site locally.
The Wordpress site is on the github and I tried to pull the codes from there and accessing site already to my local machine but when I tried to access the site locally it always saying

> "Error establishing a database connection"

I already checked DB_NAME, DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD inside `wp-config.php` and already created a database inside phpMyadmin locally and imported the DB from github but still the problem is there.
Is there anything wrong with my configurations or steps that I am doing?
Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

Comment: You're sure that the user named in your `wp-config.php` file's `DB_USER` constant has access to the database?

Comment: Hi @PatJ thanks for the answer. So the wp-config.php in Github and wp-config.php on my local setup is different right or it's the same? Because what I did is I import the DB from the github and put on my local phpmyadmin and create another DB to put inside on it and create some privileges access but still I got an error about this.

Comment: Your `wp-config.php` file should reflect your server's setup. `DB_USER` and `DB_PASS` should be set to the username and password you want WordPress to use to access the database. See [this article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/) for more on what you need to update in `wp-config.php`.